# Converting unknown binary data into series of numbers? (with a known example)

Tags: unix, binary

I'm trying to find a way to convert files in a little-used archaic file format into something human readable...

As an example, od -x myfile gives:

```
0000000      2800    4620    1000    461e    c800    461d    a000    461e
0000020      8000    461e    2800    461e    5000    461f    b800    461e
0000040      b800    461d    4000    461c    a000    461e    3800    4620
0000060      f800    4621    7800    462a    e000    4622    2800    463c
0000100      2000    464a    1000    4654    8c00    4693    5000    4661
0000120      7000    46ac    6c00    46d1    a400    4695    3c00    470a
0000140      b000    46ca    7400    46e9    c200    471b    9400    469e
0000160      9c00    4709    cc00    4719    4000    46b0    6400    46cc
...
```

which I know corresponds to these integers:

```
10250   10116   10098   10152   10144   10122   10196   10158
10094   10000   10152   10254   10366   10910   10424   12042
12936   13572   18886   14420   22072   ...
```

but I have no idea how to convert one to the other!!

Many many thanks to anyone who can help.

If possible, general tips for what to try/where to begin in this situation would also be appreciated.

**Update:** I put the full binary file online here http://pastebin.com/YL2ApExG and the numbers it corresponds to here http://pastebin.com/gXNntsaJ

In the hex dump, it seems to alternate between four digits, presumably they correspond to the numbers I want? separated either by 4600 or 4700. Unfortunately, I don't know where to go from here!

Someone else asked below: the binary file is a .dat file generated by an old spectroscopy program... it's 1336 bytes and corresponds to 334 integers, so it's four bytes per integer.

Comment: I should add that "od -d myfile" gives plausible looking numbers, but is wrong: the first number it gives is 10240 (i.e. 10 off), and the rest are incorrect. I don't know if this is a coincidence or not... I'm out of my depth here!

Comment: Did you run the `od` command on an Intel processor (e.g. PC) or a Motorola processor (e.g. Macintosh)?  In other words, is the output big- or little-endian?

Comment: How many bytes are in your file, and how many integers does it correspond to?

Comment: I still doubt you have the valid conversion. However, you can use the following answer to convert the hex values to decimal.

Comment: I ran it on an Intel processor. The binary file is just a .dat, 1336 bytes, and it corresponds to 334 integers.

Comment: I should add that I got the bytecount with "wc -c". The .dat file

Comment: you should amend your main question text with the answers to these question. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure that the numbers that the file converted to in you above example is correct? Do you have any documentation as to the format of the binary file (i.e size etc)?

Comment: No documentation, I'm afraid. And I'm 99% sure they are correct. The software program that generates them has an "export" function. If you export to data, you get the binary data, if you export to text, you get that list of numbers. Unfortunately, the software in question only runs on an old computer that I don't have personal access to right now, and I have tonnes of these files to convert...

Comment: @user6...62 - Do you have the source code?

Comment: I wish I had the source code! Unfortunately, I don't... I'm afraid I'm stuck with just the files. I am sure those numbers are correct however (not to mention it seems too much of a coincidence that the filesize of the .dat file would be 4 times the number of integers too).

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what you can do -

**Step I: Do the od -x of the file and redirect it to a temp file (eg. hexdump.txt)**

```
od -x myfile > hexdump.txt
```

**Step II: You will now have a text file that contains hexadecimal values which you can view using the cat command. Something like this -**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat hexdump.txt
0000000      2800    4620    1000    461e    c800    461d    a000    461e
0000020      8000    461e    2800    461e    5000    461f    b800    461e
0000040      b800    461d    4000    461c    a000    461e    3800    4620
0000060      f800    4621    7800    462a    e000    4622    2800    463c
0000100      2000    464a    1000    4654    8c00    4693    5000    4661
0000120      7000    46ac    6c00    46d1    a400    4695    3c00    470a
0000140      b000    46ca    7400    46e9    c200    471b    9400    469e
0000160      9c00    4709    cc00    4719    4000    46b0    6400    46cc
```

**Step III: The first column isn't really important to you. Columns 2 thru 9 are important. We will now strip the file using AWK so that you can convert it to decimal. We will add space so that we can consider each value as an individual field. We will also add "0x" to it so that we can pass it as a hexadecimal value.**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "0x"$i" "}' hexdump.txt > hexdump1.txt

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat hexdump1.txt
0x2800 0x4620 0x1000 0x461e 0xc800 0x461d 0xa000 0x461e 0x8000 0x461e 0x2800 0x461e 0x5000 0x461f 0xb800 0x461e 0xb800 0x461d 0x4000 0x461c 0xa000 0x461e 0x3800 0x4620 0xf800 0x4621 0x7800 0x462a 0xe000 0x4622 0x2800 0x463c 0x2000 0x464a 0x1000 0x4654 0x8c00 0x4693 0x5000 0x4661 0x7000 0x46ac 0x6c00 0x46d1 0xa400 0x4695 0x3c00 0x470a 0xb000 0x46ca 0x7400 0x46e9 0xc200 0x471b 0x9400 0x469e 0x9c00 0x4709 0xcc00 0x4719 0x4000 0x46b0 0x6400 0x46cc
```

**Step IV: Now we will convert each hexadecimal value into decimal using printf function with AWK.**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ gawk --non-decimal-data '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ("%05d ", $i)}' hexdump1.txt > hexdump2.txt

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat hexdump2.txt
10240 17952 04096 17950 51200 17949 40960 17950 32768 17950 10240 17950 20480 17951 47104 17950 47104 17949 16384 17948 40960 17950 14336 17952 63488 17953 30720 17962 57344 17954 10240 17980 08192 17994 04096 18004 35840 18067 20480 18017 28672 18092 27648 18129 41984 18069 15360 18186 45056 18122 29696 18153 49664 18203 37888 18078 39936 18185 52224 18201 16384 18096 25600 18124
```

**Step V: Formatting to make it easily readable**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed 's/.\{48\}/&\n/g' < hexdump2.txt > hexdump3.txt

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat hexdump3.txt
10240 17952 04096 17950 51200 17949 40960 17950 
32768 17950 10240 17950 20480 17951 47104 17950 
47104 17949 16384 17948 40960 17950 14336 17952 
63488 17953 30720 17962 57344 17954 10240 17980 
08192 17994 04096 18004 35840 18067 20480 18017 
28672 18092 27648 18129 41984 18069 15360 18186 
45056 18122 29696 18153 49664 18203 37888 18078 
39936 18185 52224 18201 16384 18096 25600 18124
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this just gives me the same output as "od -d", so doesn't help me much with my problem! I do appreciate the lesson in awk/sed though, so your effort wasn't wasted :)

Comment: No problem. Can you elaborate more on the issue you are facing? I thought the conversion of Hex to Dec is what you were looking for? "`but I have no idea how to convert one to the other!!`"

Comment: What do you get when you do `hexdump -C binary_file`? Can you put that up please?

Comment: Sure! I put it up [here](http://pastebin.com/YL2ApExG), since it wouldn't fit in the comment box, and [this is the series of ints it corresponds to](http://pastebin.com/gXNntsaJ). Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks for the hexdump of your binary file. How do you get the decimal integers? Is it a separate file or another binary file?

Comment: It's a separate file. I answered this above; I once had access to the original program responsible for these files. It could export the same data either as .dat or as .txt -- the hexdump is from the .dat, and the list of integers is the contents of the .txt file. I just have a bunch of the dat files I need to convert, and I don't have access to the original program anymore. Thanks again for your continued help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still doesn't seems that the Decimal file shown here is converted from this particular binary.

Comment: Agreeing with @Jaypal. given the inputs and outputs, it seems possible that your sample output is not for the input file that you have. Do you have a way to confirm they are a matched pair? Good luck!